# How to run a command in zsh as you type in the shell?

Tags: shell, zsh, zshrc

I'm trying to create a bindkey for zsh to run a command (fzf) after typing the characters `vim`  (notice the space after the 'm'). That way, I would get a fzf instance without having to press `^t`.

The problem I'm having is that viins only allows one character input. So this would work:

```
bindkey -M viins 'v' fzf-file-widget
```

While this won't work:

```
bindkey -M viins 'vim ' fzf-file-widget
```

Is there a way to achieve this?